# How can I extract the contents of TR tags from HTML using server-side JavaScript's RegExp?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, node.js

I can't seem to solve this seemingly easy problem.

Assume that there will never be nesting of tr inside a tr (hence no need for a full blown parser).

```
var HTMLtoParse = 'anything before <tr>1 blah<td></td>gsdgfs</tr> dfg <tr>2 blah<td></td>sdgfs</tr> anything after ';

var magicRE = /????/g;

var desiredOutput = HTMLtoParse.match(magicRE);
```

Where desiredOutput is

```
[
  '<tr>1 blah<td></td>gsdgfs</tr>',
  '<tr>2 blah<td></td>sdgfs</tr>'
]
```

Cheers in advance

Comment: Sorry, that is not a duplicate? Read the question

Comment: Despite the dozens of warnings you saw when you googled "parsing html with regex" (and the definitive answer on that supposed duplicate), you still think this is a good idea?

Comment: @RobertHarvey All warnings tell you regexp does not work well with html because of nesting, and they all suggest a recursive decent parser. But since there will never be a TR inside a TR there is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var HTMLtoParse = 'anything before <tr>1 blah<td></td>gsdgfs</tr> dfg <tr>2 blah<td></td>sdgfs</tr> anything after ';
var res = HTMLtoParse.match(/<tr>.*?<\/tr>/g);
console.log(res);
```